# Выдает ошибку : TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python

Дан файл, содержащий различные даты. Каждая дата — это число месяц
и год. Найти год с наименьшим номером.

```
import csv

d =[]
with open(r'C:\\Users\\79654\\Desktop\\История\\2laba8.txt','r+',encoding='cp1251') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ",")
    for row in reader:
        d.append(row)
        min_year = int(row.get("год"))
for i in d:
    if min_year >= int(i.get("год")):
        min_year = int(i.get("год"))
print(f"Наименьший год {min_year}")
print("Весна")
for i in d:
    if (int(i.get("месяц")) > 2) and (int(i.get("месяц")) < 6):
        print(i)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject1\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    min_year = int(row.get("год"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Файл:

```
день,месяц,год
12,12,2020
11,04,2019
15,05,1998
20,07,2016
10,01,1988
20,01,2001
01,01,1967
01,05,1999
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). Добавьте пример файла, чтобы можно было проверить у себя

Comment: А так, у вас какой-то `.get(` вернул `None`, т.к. не было такого ключа, а `int(None)` приведет к такой ошибке. Но в какой именно строке ошибка не скажу - нужен стек ошибки

Comment: Ну так распечатайте вначале что у вас `row.get(“год”)` возвращает. Скорее всего там будет «год» в качестве значения. А если так, то очевидно в чём ошибка.

Comment: Ну вы когда шапку файла читаете `день,месяц,год` у вас и не получается эти строки в числа перевести. Надо шапку пропускать. А лучше возьмите библиотеку `Pandas` и не мучайтесь чтением `csv` файлов "вручную".

Comment: @0andriy, `csv.DictReader` сам "пропускает" шапку файла csv, он использует значения из нее как ключи словаря для каждой строки. Просто похоже что фактическая кодировка не cp1251, из-за этого в словаре не "год", а `"РіРѕРґ"` например: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOXvg.png (добавил `print(row)` перед `min_year = int(row.get("год"))`)

Comment: @insolor, ах, ну да, скрипт-то скорее всего написан в UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите библиотеку `Pandas` и не мучайтесь (из файла читать `csv` будет ещё проще, чем из переменной - просто укажите имя файла в `read_csv`). `Pandas` сама соображает, что первая строка - это заголовок (если заголовок имеет другой формат, это легко настраивается):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = """ \
день,месяц,год
12,12,2020
11,04,2019
15,05,1998
20,07,2016
10,01,1988
20,01,2001
01,01,1967
01,05,1999"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
print('Весна')
print(df[(df['месяц'] > 2) & (df['месяц'] < 6)])
```

Вывод:

```
Весна
    день  месяц   год
1     11      4  2019
2     15      5  1998
7      1      5  1999
```

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка в том что cp1251 не читает числа как 2230, 4023, и так далее. Поэтому лучше использовать utf-8. Когда cp1251 не принимает числа то он просто отправляет `None` так как он не видит такие числа

```py
import csv

d =[]
with open(r'text.txt','r+',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ",")
    for row in reader:
        d.append(row)
        min_year = int(row.get("год"))
        
for i in d:
    if min_year >= int(i.get("год")):
        min_year = int(i.get("год"))
print(f"Наименьший год {min_year}")
print("Весна")
for i in d:
    if (int(i.get("месяц")) > 2) and (int(i.get("месяц")) < 6):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Причина в кодировке, но объяснение неправильное. Числа в кодировках utf-8 и cp1251 выглядят одинаково, а вот шапка будет выглядеть по-разному (из-за того что используется кириллица).

Comment: `Когда cp1251 не принимает числа то он просто отправляет None так как он не видит такие числа` - вот это "грубо говоря чепуха", как вы выразились в комментарии к вопросу. Ошибка происходит после чтения первого ряда данных при попытке вытащить данные по ключу `"год"` из переменной `row`, при том что в этой переменной лежит словарь `{'РґРµРЅСЊ': '12', 'РјРµСЃСЏС†': '12', 'РіРѕРґ': '2020'}` из-за неправильной кодировки.

Comment: None - результат, который возвращает метод get, когда запрошенный ключ в словаре не найден, а не "Когда cp1251 не принимает числа то он просто отправляет None так как он не видит такие числа"

Comment: * Чуть ошибся: `Ошибка происходит после чтения первого ряда данных при попытке вытащить данные по ключу "год" из переменной row` - не при попытке вытаскивания конечно же, а позже, при попытке конвертировать None, который вернул метод get словаря, в целое число.

Comment: Ок но я не согласен с вами

Comment: Если вы не согласны, возможно вы укажете в чем конкретно я не прав, по вашему мнению?

Comment: Ну точнее сказать что я НЕ понял про что вы говорите шапку. Как я понял шапка это слова в самом начале тоесть слова год, месяц, день. И исходя от этого что мой ответ ДОЛЖЕН быть правильным из-за того что мы говорим одно и тоже но вы отрицаете мой ответ, из-за того что я неправильно пояснил(хотя мне кажется иначе) Но моя самая главная проблема в том что мой ответ верный, но пояснение кривее чем должно быть.